# Changing message output in PostgreSQL and pgAdminIII

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

This is a small thing, but it's a bit annoying to me and seems like there is probably a way to configure it.  Let's say I have the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION baz()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'I also did some work!';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bar()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'I did a bunch of work and want you to know about it';
  PERFORM baz();
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  PERFORM bar();
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

select foo();
```

I get the following output messages:

```
NOTICE:  I did a bunch of work and want you to know about it
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT bar()"
PL/pgSQL function "foo" line 4 at PERFORM
NOTICE:  I also did some work!
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT baz()"
PL/pgSQL function "bar" line 5 at PERFORM
SQL statement "SELECT bar()"
PL/pgSQL function "foo" line 4 at PERFORM
Total query runtime: 31 ms.
1 row retrieved.
```

What I want (usually) is to just see something like:

```
NOTICE:  I did a bunch of work and want you to know about it
NOTICE:  I also did some work!
Total query runtime: 31 ms.
1 row retrieved.
```

Is there a way to control/alter this?  Again, it's a small thing and hardly worth a question on Stackoverflow, but if you have a lot of stuff going on it starts to introduce a lot of "noise" into the output and it makes my already overloaded brain hurt trying to sift through it.  :)

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.5 with pgAdminIII 1.16.0

Answer (score 3):

Try connecting with `-q` option.  The q stands for Quiet and may be what you need.

```
psql -q -d foo_db
```

you may also try:

- `\set verbosity terse`
- `\set quiet on`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...  but, I do most of my work in pgAdminIII, so I'm not sure if this will help me.

Comment: Oddly enough you need to specify VERBOSITY in caps or it doesn't work, at least in 9.5.9. So to remove context from psql use \set VERBOSITY terse  ... this gets me every single time.

Comment: @DoctorEval I haven’t needed to set this in some time, so allow me to follow up on this before I update the answer (unless someone else can verify your findings). If that’s the case (1) good observation! (2) I’m curious why this would change (3) I’m curious if it’s intentional (and not a bug) — thanks!

Comment: for what it's worth I tried this again last night and confirmed the behaviour (in 9.5.9). "\set verbosity terse" doesn't work, but "\set VERBOSITY terse" does. No wonder I can never remember how it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control over messaging and interface, it might be worth moving to a real scripting language. Writing database scripts in tools like Python with `psycopg2` or Perl with `DBD::Pg` and `DBI` is pretty simple.

Not only does using a real scripting language give you total control over messaging, but it also gives you control over error handling, gives you loops and other control structures, and generally offers a much nicer model than raw `SQL` for scripting tasks.

Comment: I'm a python developer and use psycopg2 where I believe it is appropriate and necessary.  But, I use plpgsql where I believe it is appropriate.  Here I'm asking a question if there is a way to suppress the context message from with in pgAdminIII.  Not via Python (I'm well aware how to do logging in Python).

Comment: @DavidS It doesn't look like it is. `CONTEXT` is always sent by the server and it's up to the client to show or not show it. `psql` offers control over this, but it looks like PgAdmin doesn't.

Comment: Yeah...  I'm thinking you are right.  I can't find a way to do it and no one is jumping in.  I thought Erwin might have a solution, but so far no word from him.  Thanks for the replies.